# How to use Akka ByteString in Spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, akka

I need to use Akka's `ByteString` in a Spark dataset because of some legacy code (so it's impossible to use anything else such as `Array[Byte]`). But Spark throws the following exception for even a simple usage of `ByteString`. How should I use it in a dataset?

```
// Code
context.session.range(1, 10).map(i => akka.util.ByteString(i.toString))

// Exception
[error] Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: akka.util.ByteString (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)                                                                               
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:496)                                                          
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:438)                                                                                                         
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)                                                                                                     
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newSequenceEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:167)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

```
scala> val akkaByteString = ByteString("xyz")
akkaByteString: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(120, 121, 122)

scala> akkaByteString.utf8String
res0: String = xyz

scala> akkaByteString.decodeString("US-ASCII")
res1: String = xyz
```

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/util/ByteString.scala#L794